# Adding class to sweet alert

Tags: javascript, less, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to add an extra class for my modal so I can select it from LESS and turn it's background to transparent. But customClass is not working. Is there any other way to do it. BTW I have already changed a lot with default classes so I need to do this for just one modal, can not effect the global swal.

```
   swal({
      title: success,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      html: true,
      customClass: ".swal-back"
   });
```

Comment: https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#classname - share some code of what you've tried, this is the additional property you need to add a new class.

Comment: Are you using SweetAlert https://sweetalert.js.org or SweetAlert2 https://sweetalert2.github.io ?

Comment: for sweetalert2 version 11.7.18, you can use mixin. https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Answer (score 17):

Assuming the OP is using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/),

The customClass has since changed from a string to an object.

It expects an object such as the following:

```
customClass: {
  container: 'your-container-class',
  popup: 'your-popup-class',
  header: 'your-header-class',
  title: 'your-title-class',
  closeButton: 'your-close-button-class',
  icon: 'your-icon-class',
  image: 'your-image-class',
  content: 'your-content-class',
  input: 'your-input-class',
  actions: 'your-actions-class',
  confirmButton: 'your-confirm-button-class',
  cancelButton: 'your-cancel-button-class',
  footer: 'your-footer-class'
}
```

The official line in docs at time of writing [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#custom-class)

On another note, be careful when using versions prior to [8.12.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2/v/8.12.2) and close to it since there was a known bug there related to custom classes.

Issue related to the topic [here](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/1623)

Comment: This is the correct answer when we use [SweatAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). but, if the class has been added, and the style still hasn't changed or is crossed out when in the inspect element, try to setting the **buttonsStyling** to **false**. this looks like: ```{customClass: {...}, buttonsStyling: false}```

Answer (score 8):

The `customClass` option has been removed. You need to use `className` now instead. The period before the class name is not necessary.

```
swal({
  title: success,
  showConfirmButton: false,
  html: true,
  className: "swal-back"
});
```

Comment: i know this is a pretty old comment, but classname is not mentioned in the package

Answer (score 0):

For sweetalert2 you can use **customClass** with name class.