# Adding a class to sweet alert 2

Tags: sweetalert2

This question has been raised for sweetalert 1
[Adding class to sweet alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985966/adding-class-to-sweet-alert)

Now my question is, how can i add a custom class in sweetalert2?

className: "new_class" does not work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `sweetalert2` the custom class can be added to multiple targets:

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
  customClass: {
    container: '...',
    popup: '...',
    title: '...',
    closeButton: '...',
    icon: '...',
    image: '...',
    htmlContainer: '...'
    input: '...',
    inputLabel: '...',
    validationMessage: '...',
    actions: '...',
    confirmButton: '...',
    denyButton: '...',
    cancelButton: '...',
    loader: '...',
    footer: '...'
    timerProgressBar: '...'
  }
})
```

Docs: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#custom-class